# I want to see tool descriptions when I hover my mouse over them

Tags: interface, customization

So I'm following tutorials to figure out and begin to use blender, but I have a problem. When they're going across the display, they'll hover the cursor over a tool, say for example Extrude Region and a little dialog box appears. In this case it reads: Extrude Region, Extrude freely or along an axis. However on my version, if I hover my cursor over the tool, I get no such dialog box. Since I'm new to the program, I'd like to be able to see them so I know what I'm clicking on. How to I make them appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get tool descriptions, go to *Preferences > Interface* and enable *Tooltips*

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had that box already checked. So I ended up restarting and then the tool tips appeared.

Comment: Glad you made it work :).